# Idiomatic way to expand escape sequences in a string in Scala

Tags: scala

I've got an input string that contains (non-Scala) escape sequences such as `\n`, `\s`, `\x20ac;` and `\{$var}`. I want to create an output string by copying ordinary characters to the output, and applying some processing to each escape sequence, copying the result of the processing to the output. The rules for processing the escape sequence and detecting where it ends both depend only on the character that appears immediately after the backslash.

What's the idiomatic way to achieve this in Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
val r = """\\[ns]|\\x[a-f0-9]{4};|\\\{\$[a-z][a-z_0-9]+\}""".r
val result = r.replaceAllIn(targetString, m =>
  // your logic. `m` is a Match. Use it to decide what to replace with.
)
```

Have a look at [Regex](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex)

You can even go further and use nice pattern matching:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex.Match
def handle(m: Match) = m match {
  case Match("""\n""") => // do stuff
  case _ => // etc.
}

val result = r.replaceAllIn(targetString, handle _)
```

Comment: Neat, I knew it had to be something easy.

Comment: I'd actually been looking for the "going further" solution without success; but because I can do a simple switch on m.charAt(1) it's not actually needed. However, there's one gotcha that I had to fix: the replacement string has to be put through Regex.quoteReplacement in case it contains any "\" or "$" characters.